# find out the parent of a link and pre-pend it with something

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, prepend

I'm trying do something like this

```
if ($(this).parent() == $('div.propdata')){

    $(this).prepend('<a class="booknow2 sidelink" href="../../availability/default.aspx"><span>Book now &raquo;</span></a>');

}
```

By the way `$(this)` is `evenprop`.

Can't seem to get it to work.

This is my code

```
<div class="propdata" id="FARM"><div class="evenprop">This is where the prepend would be</div></div>
```

I need it to only prepend that bit if the parent of `evenprop` is `propdata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector on [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see if it matched, like this:

```
if ($(this).parent('div.propdata').length){
  $(this).prepend('<a class="booknow2 sidelink" href="../../availability/default.aspx"><span>Book now &raquo;</span></a>');
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JT8Uj/), since [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) only returns the immediate parent *if* it matches the selector, it's a quicker test than `.parent().is(selector)`.